# Placing logo image into navbar

Tags: reactjs, image, material-ui, navbar

I am getting a broken image when I put my logo inside of the navbar. I have it saved locally inside the public folder.

I have tried passing as a prop, and directly linking to the path, but i cannot seem to get it to work.

```
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar'
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
const NavBar = () => {
  return(
    <div>
      <AppBar className='nav-bar' position="static" color='white'>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="title" >
          <img src='../../public/LQ_Logo.png' width={182} height={64} />
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  )
};
export default NavBar;
```

I need the logo to be displayed in the left corner of the navbar

Comment: Are you sure you need to use '../'? When the program runs it will probably run from the public folder or a subdir.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `img` within `Public` folder use relative path to `Public`.

For `public/Vector.png` use `./Vector.png`.

Moreover, if it's a `SVG` you can import it as `ReactComponent`, for example:

```js
import { ReactComponent as CatImg } from "./add-debug.svg";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar className="nav-bar" position="static" color="white">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="title">
            <CatImg height={100} />
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="title">
            <img src="./Vector.png" alt="bug" height={100} />
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Demo:

[image: Edit practical-minsky-lbw0q]

Answer (score 2):

Did you check that relative path is correct? Maybe something is missing in "../../public/LQ_Logo.png".

You can try to use this alternative:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
const App = () => (
  <div>
    {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
    <Logo />
  </div>
);
```

Change the png image to svg (is better to escalate width/heigh for web), and then import the image as a component and call the component in your code.